# Visual Basic Random Number/Mod

Tags: vb.net, division, modulo

I am currently working on some homework for my Visual Basics class

I have to generate two random numbers, then either add them, subtract them, divide them, or multiply them. (the user would try to guess the answer)

The only problem I am going to run into is when I want to divide.

I need the numbers to be generated, and be divisible. I am so lost of how I could do that, and google, and reading through my textbook is no help.

Comment: Pick a random number.  Pick another temp one.  Multiply them.  Use the first and third (if I grok the question correctly).  Not much of a guessing game - more like a math quiz.  PS. it is singular: *Visual Basic*

Comment: What do you mean by divisible?  And post the code you have so far.

Comment: I assume they mean that the need a whole number as an answer so they just need to check to see if the denominator is bigger then the numerator

Comment: I assume "_be divisible_" you mean that you wish to cater for division by zero errors?

Comment: OP means that the chosen numbers need to be such that the answer is an integer I think.

Answer (score 0):

This function will generate a `Tuple` of two numbers which when the first is divided by the second, you'll get an answer that is an integer. A `Tuple` is simply collection of related pieces of data, kind of like a `Structure`

```
Private Function GenerateNumbers() As Tuple(Of Integer, Integer)
    Dim rnd As New Random
    'The two lines below generate a
    Dim x As Integer = rnd.Next(99) + 1
    Dim y As Integer = rnd.Next(99) + 1
    Do Until x Mod y = 0
        x = rnd.Next(99) + 1
        y = rnd.Next(99) + 1
    Loop
    Dim result As New Tuple(Of Integer, Integer)(x, y)
    Return result
End Function
```

To access the numbers, use something like this in your code ..

```
Dim number1, number2 As Integer
Dim NewNumbers As Tuple(Of Integer, Integer)
NewNumbers = GenerateNumbers()
number1 = NewNumbers.Item1
number2 = NewNumbers.Item2
```